# my request.body in node.js rest api creation is undefined

Tags: node.js, postman

my node.js rest api code (partial):

```
app.post('/save',function(req, res) {

  console.log(req.body);
    fs.writeFile(__dirname + "/" + "users.json",req.body,function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
  })

});
```

from postman i call this rest end point with 
`{ "name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York" }` data as my body in application/json format

but in console i get the value as undefined and even in the file  users.json i get the value undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot body-parser add these lines at top

> npm install --save body-parser

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```